# Issues with putting dockerized Postgres OLTP database in read only

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have a dockerized postgres 9.3.5 OLTP instance that I'm going to update to 9.5.2. Instead of shutting it down and doing a pg_dumpal to a file and then load it I would like to spin up a new docker container and pipe the database `pg_dumpall -h localhost -p [port] -U postgres | psql -h localhost -U postgres -p [port]`. I'm thinking I could alter the `postgresql.conf` to be in read only mode. This would temporarily mess with my app but at least users could still `SELECT`. Is there a better way to go about this? Are there any big issues with putting in read only mode while I pipe the database over?

Comment: This is not really a programming question.

Comment: I would not mess around with read-only mode. Why not treat the new copy as a slave in a master-slave situation?

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Replication,_Clustering,_and_Connection_Pooling

Comment: @ZanLynx I currently don't have any replication setup for this instance. The plan is to setup pgpool eventually (3-4 months) but at this point it would be easier to bring it down and do a dump than setup pgpool to do a slave update and then failover. I just wasn't sure if there was a better way. Maybe there's not??
I can move this to dba stack if that's a better fit.